# Как избежать повторного входа в аккаунт Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Каждый раз открывается стартовая страница, где нужно ввести логин и пароль. Есть ли вариант избежать этого, чтобы ввести один раз и вход был выполнен для каждой следующей сессии?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я это делал через отдельный профиль в браузере.

Шаги (для Firefox):

- Создал отдельный профиль (в адресной строке `about:profiles`)
- Запустил браузер с новым профилем
- Зашел и авторизовался на сайте (куки получил)
- В selenium'е указывал тот профиль

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/1dde0a42ba93fe89609855d6db8af1c63b1ab7cc/submitting_water_meter_readings/utils.py#L35)

```
    ...
    profile_directory = r'%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\p75l82q1.for_mail__selenium'
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(os.path.expandvars(profile_directory))

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile, options=options)
```