# Selenium Telegram. Сохраняю cookies, но авторизация все равно сбрасывается

Tags: python, selenium, telegram

```
async def run_browser(user_data=False):
    """ ===== Запускаем браузер ===== """
    ua = UserAgent()
    userAgent = ua.random
    options = Options()

    proxy = await tobase.get_one_proxy()
    if proxy:
        server = proxy['addr']
        port = proxy['port']
        auth = proxy['username']
        password = proxy['password']
        options.add_argument(f'--proxy-type=http')
        options.add_argument(f'--proxy={server}:{port}')
        options.add_argument(f'--proxy-auth={auth}:{password}')
    
    if user_data:
        options.add_argument("user-data-dir=user_data\\"+user_data)
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["ignore-certificate-errors"])
    br = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)

    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-setuid-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    options.add_argument("--window-size-minimize_window")
    options.add_argument(f"--user-agent={userAgent}")
    options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
    
    return br
```

Возможно ли обойтись без сохранения userdata, уж слишком много он всего сохраняет.

Comment: Мб заранее авторизоваться и по сохраненном в профиле кукам заходить? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1228264/201445

Comment: в каком месте вашего кода сохраняются cookies?